# connect to kibana index using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I'm a beginner in using Kibana and I want to query my data using Python script, I'm not sure about how to connect to my Kibana index:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
```

here is how I used elasticsearch library, but I'm not sure which parameters I have to pass to Elasticsearch object and how I should authenticate to Kibana.

Could you please give me any example or use case to explain me how should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect with your Elasticsearch you need at least:

- ip address of your node
- scheme of your connection
- port to your Elasticsearch

For example:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(["node_ip_address:9200", scheme="http", port=9200])
```

To send data to Elasticsearch index you need to call `index()` method.
For example:

```
es.index(index="myIndex", body="My first document", id=1)
```

If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here. ELK Stack has very well written documentation which should be easy to understand. Below you have some useful links.

[Python-Elasticsearch plugin docs with examples](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.13.0/)

[Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html)

[Kibana documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index.html)

Comment: @rufy26 please go through the answer and let me know if this resolves your issue.